# I need to replicate a number x times across a row but as a multiplier in excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

If you look at the first row for instance - I need to replicate the Qty "3" in 2.8 cells - so basically the last cell (3rd cell) will contain 3*.8 = 2.4 Hours basically. Hope this explains clearly.

```
Qty | Hours |                           
3   | 2.8   | 3     | 3     | 2.4   |       |       |       |       | 
7   | 4.6   | 7     | 7     | 7     | 7     | 4.2   |       |       | 
5   | 7.6   | 5     | 5     | 5     | 5     | 5     | 5     | 5     | 3
0.5 | 3.5   | 0.5   | 0.5   | 0.5   | 0.25  |       |       |       | 
4   | 6.3   | 4     | 4     | 4     | 4     | 4     | 4     | 1.2   |
```

Comment: sorry, you lost me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have too many rows to cover, try this...

```
Sub ApplyHours()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim R As Range
    Dim I As Long
    Dim L As Long
    Dim dblDecimal As Double

    For Each R In Range(Range("A2"), Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        L = Int(R.Offset(0, 1))
        For I = 2 To L + 2
            R.Offset(0, I) = IIf(I = L + 2, (R.Offset(0, 1) - L) * R, R)
        Next
    Next R
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

hope it helps...

Answer (score 1):

Put this in C2 copy across far enough to cover the furthest and down:

```
=IF(COLUMN(A:A) > INT($B2)+1,"",IF(COLUMN(A:A)<=INT($B2),$A2,MOD($B2,1)*$A2))
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

---

As per your comments it is apparent that the numbers in Column B are not exact number by displayed rounded numbers.  It what is wanted is the rounded number to one decimal then use this:

```
=IF(COLUMN(A:A) > INT($B2)+1,"",IF(COLUMN(A:A)<=INT($B2),$A2,MOD(ROUND($B2,1),1)*$A2))
```

Comment: thank you scott - just one little problem - the last number is off for some reason at times. I will have hundreds of row so the issue will be all over. When I dragged it across and down as well this is what I get:

3 2.8 3 3 2.256880734     
7 4.6 7 7 7 7 4.083333333   
5 7.6 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 3
0.5 3.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.25    
4 6.3 4 4 4 4 4 4 1

Comment: I could not remember the INT formula and wound up going with QUOTIENT(X,1)

Comment: @guy I would need to see more than it is simply not working.  As you can see from the data above, which I did not cheat or Photoshop, the data is correct.

Comment: I was going to ask how is it off in the last number?

Comment: @guy do you use , or ; as list separators in your version of excel ?

Comment: sorry I hit enter and it posted my response instead of going to the next line
thank you scott - just one little problem - the last number is off for some reason at times. I will have hundreds of row so the issue will be all over. When I dragged it across and down as well this is what I get:

3 2.8 3 3 2.256880734     
7 4.6 7 7 7 7 4.083333333   
5 7.6 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 3
0.5 3.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.25    
4 6.3 4 4 4 4 4 4 1

Comment: What column does your data start in?

Comment: Then @guy Either the first or the second has more decimal points than what is being shown.  Excel will store up to I believe 14 decimal points but you can determine how many are shown and excel will display the rounded number, but use the full number in any math.  My guess is that the 2.8 is more like 2.789097

Comment: i do not use list separators as i do not know them

you did everything right in your formula - just the last number i get when i paste the formula is giving me some decimals off. For instance when for the first row i get 2.25 in the last number instead of 2.4

in the second row i get 4.08 for the last number instead of 4.2

Comment: @guy I will bet that your actual number in B2 is 2.752294, which when forced to display only one decimal shows 2.8, while keeping the underlying value. This underlying value is what excel uses for any math to avoid rounding errors.  Click on B2 and then increses the number of decimals shown and you will see what I am saying.

Comment: @guy, see scotts comments that you may have more decimal points than your a displaying for columns A and B.  Set format to General for those columns and see if they display more decimal values when you do.

Comment: If you want to limit your results to 1 decimal for column B, modify the last part of scott's formula to `MOD(round($B2,1),1)

Answer (score 1):

While speed meister Scott Craner was busy answering while I was formatting and double checking my results, I came up with the following for cell C2 which can be copied down and to the right as far as needed.

```
=IF(QUOTIENT($B2,COLUMN(A1))>0, $A2,IF(COLUMN(A1)-QUOTIENT($B2,1)=1,MOD($B2,1)*$A2,""))
```

Or if you want to round the decimal place of column B to 1 decimal place you can use:

```
=IF(QUOTIENT($B2,COLUMN(A1))>0, $A2,IF(COLUMN(A1)-QUOTIENT($B2,1)=1,MOD(ROUND($B2,1),1)*$A2,""))
```

Proof of Concept

[image: Proof of Concept]

Comment: Mine's shorter. 8P

Comment: @ScottCraner not only that but better 8)  I showed more variety! 8)  then again maybe not.

Comment: haha thanks guys but both formulas give me the last number which is off and NOT because of extra decimals. 3 x 0.8 = 2.4 NOT 2.25688. If you do the formula for the first 2 rows and see the last number you will see what i mean. Since these are hours the accuracy matters for my results :(
thanks again

Comment: when you put in the formula =B2*100  where B2 is your cell with 2.8 in it what do you get as an answer? and same goes for =A2*100, what is the answer?

Comment: @guy how is the number of hours brought in?  You have two formulas that return correct when we hand enter the number 2.8.  The fault is not in the formulas but in the data.  Your .8 is not a .8 but .752294, math does not lie.

Comment: @guy, In a cell that is formatted "General" put `=A2*B2` and you will see what I mean.

Comment: okay sorry guys .. it was my excel - i closed all my excel sheets and restarted excel and your formulas work excellent - sorry to be a bother. Don't know why it does that but thanks a lot :)

Comment: @guy now choose the one you used as the correct answer by clicking on the check mark by the answer you used.  It is something only those who post the question can do.